# result from specific group in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Suppose I have following information,
#PAN#       #Product#
AAAAAAAAAA  Product1
AAAAAAAAAA  Product2
AAAAAAAAAA  Product3
AAAAAAAAAA  **Product4**
AAAAAAAAAA  Product5
BBBBBBBBBB  Product1
BBBBBBBBBB  Product2
BBBBBBBBBB  Product3
BBBBBBBBBB  **Product4**
BBBBBBBBBB  Product5
CCCCCCCCCC  Product1
DDDDDDDDDD  Product2
```

I want only those PANs where Product <>'Product4' (CCCCCCCCCC,DDDDDDDDDD), but it giving me wrong result as same PANs are in other products(Product1,Product2,Product3,Product5) also.
So instead of giving result (CCCCCCCCCC,DDDDDDDDDD), it is giving (AAAAAAAAAA,BBBBBBBBBB,CCCCCCCCCC,DDDDDDDDDD)

Comment: What query do you have so far?

Comment: select PAN from XYZ where PRODUCT<>'Product4', I know it doesn't make sense.I have used many ways but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach with left join

```
select a.*
from table1 a
left join table1 b on a.PAN = b.PAN and b.Product = 'Product4'
where b.PAN is null
```

Or using conditional aggregation

```
select a.PAN
from table1 a
group by PAN
having count(case when Product = 'Product4' then 1 else null end) = 0
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f1a106/9)

Comment: in your first method,shall we need to add `distinct`?

Comment: @lucumt yes if we have multiple entries with same PAN

Comment: Hi Khalid, Thanks for your response. I think using first query I am getting correct result. Second one is not working for me and not even giving same result. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need something like:

```
SELECT PAN from myTable 
WHERE PAN NOT IN ( SELCT PAN from myTable 
WHERE Product ='Product4')
```